# How to translate sentence like "Art of + doing something"

Tags: english-to-german, gerund

How to express something like "**Art of speaking** with strangers"  and  "**Experience of working** in a restaurant.." in German?

I just have a vague idea that the bold text have something to do with gerunds but I have no idea how gerunds work in German.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What are your vague ideas? That woudl be your own effort shown. Thanks.

Comment: I think that this is a legitimate question, as the answer is a specific non-obvious infinitive construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a construction that goes like this:

> NP, X zu Y

where NP is some noun phrase (usually just a noun), Y in an infinitive, and X is a complement of the verb in Y (mostly an object or prepositional phrase).  Examples:

> Die Kunst, mit Fremden zu sprechen.

> Die Erfahrung, in einem Restaurant zu arbeiten.

> Die Fertigkeit, Motorräder zu reparieren.

> Das gewöhnungsbedürftige Erlebnis, sich selbst von außen beobachten zu können.

(The last example is more complex, with more complements, to show how to extend the pattern a bit.)

The term "gerund" is not usually used in German grammar.  This is just an *Infinitivkonstruktion*.

Comment: I'm having a hard time adjusting to the usage of infinitives (in place where English employs gerunds) in German. How would I express something like "This place is **for buying** new books, not **for selling** old books." in German?

Comment: Would translate to "Dieser Ort existiert, um neue Bücher **zu kaufen**, nicht um alte **zu verkaufen**".

Comment: Somewhere I have read that the capitalized infinitive is the closest equivalent of gerund in German. Would you please give an example where it is used? Also you have mentioned that gerund isn't usually used in German grammar, does that mean it exists? @phipsgabler

Comment: @Tobey Yes, that would probably be closer. You could say things like _die Kunst des Sprechens mit Fremden_, but this kind of phrasing is much less idiomatic. The difference is that English has two morphologically different verbal nouns (infinitive and gerund), while in German, there is only one. You can just "reinterpret" the infinitive as a noun, so there is no need to give it an separate name (capitalization is only for orthographic consistency, the syntactic function is uniquely defined).

Comment: I'd say that nominalized (= capitalized) infinitives are mostly used in _Nominalstil_ sentences, and mainly for subjects. Inflecting them looks "too complicated". Vgl: _das Betreten der Wiese ist verboten_ (sounds like law, but fine) vs. _das Verbot des Betretens der Wiese besteht aufgrund ..._: still OK in legalese, but _das Verbot, die Wiese zu betreten, besteht aufgrund ..._ is much preferred. The distincion is only stylistic, though -- the meanings are equivalent.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Arguably, as long as it's just a single verb without any objects, the form with the capitalized infinitive is indeed idiomatic. "Die Kunst des Sprechens" is totally fine, "die Kunst des Sprechens mit Fremden" and "die Kunst des mit-Fremden-Sprechens" are both very awkward.

Comment: @Tobey You first comment is an additional question, thus you should officially make it a new question.